# Show that $\frac{z}{1 + z^2}$ does not have an antiderivative on $\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| > 2 \rbrace$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that $\frac{z}{1 + z^2}$ does not have an antiderivative on $\lbrace z \in \mathbb{C} \mid |z| > 2 \rbrace$. This makes sense intuitively, as the antiderivative would have to be some sort of logarithm, but how do I show this? I thought about integrating around some closed contour $\gamma(t) = re^{it}$ for $t \in [0, 2\pi], r > 2$ and showing that this integral does not yield 0, but I don't actually know how to evaluate this:

$$ \int_\gamma \frac{z}{1+z^2}  dz = ir \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{re^{it}}{1 + re^{2it}}e^{it}dt = ir^2 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{e^{2it}}{1 + re^{2it}}dt$$

It might also make sense to apply Morera's Theorem here, but again, I am having trouble evaluating the actual integrals.

Comment: That integral can be easily computed using residue theorem, but it seems that you don't know it. Have you tried using partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: We haven't covered the residue theorem in class yet. For partial fraction decomposition, it looks like the resulting integral would look quite similar to the one in the original post, so I'm not sure how that would help

Comment: After partial fraction decomposition, the numerators will be constants, and then integrating will be a lot easier (this is what partial fraction decomposition was invented for, afaik).

Comment: This would mean $\int_\gamma \frac{z}{1+z^2}  dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z - i}  dz + \frac{1}{2}\int_\gamma \frac{1}{z + i}  dz $ (if I computed the decomposition correctly). But then, when plugging in $\gamma$ and $\gamma'$, I am again integrating over a fraction of exponential functions, which I don't know how to evaluate.

Comment: do you know Cauchy's theorem and consequently that the value of integrals is unchanged by a homotopy of the path (i.e if you deform the path the integral value remains the same)? because these are really fundamental tools for integration (and in this case the residue theorem is very easily proved if you know these facts); otherwise one is essentially handicapped.

Comment: Yes, I do. I thought about using that to simplify the integral, but I wasn't sure how.

Comment: Ok, so imagine drawing a big circle. Inside the circle are the two "bad points" $i$ and $-i$ (as you can see from the partial fraction decomposition). Your first term $\frac{1}{2}\int_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{z-i}$ will be equal (because we can deform the path) to $\frac{1}{2}\int_{|z-i|=1}\frac{dz}{z-i}=\frac{1}{2}\cdot 2\pi i$ (this last equality is a simple direct calculation). Can you deal with the other term? Just FYI: some special cases of the residue theorem are essentially proven like this: reduce a path integral to a sum of integrals over small loops around each singularity.

Comment: Thank you! The whole thing should evaluate to $2\pi i$ then, right? And the non-existence of the antiderivative follows from the failure of the fundamental theorem?

Comment: yes that's right (having an anti-derivative would mean the integral over a closed loop is $0$ which is not the case here).

Comment: What about the fact that the region has a hole in it?  It's not simply connected.

Comment: @ChrisCuster afaik that doesn't guarantee that an anti-derivative won't exist. For example, $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ does have an antiderivative on this region.

Comment: @toluene my point was that I didn't follow the arguments being pursued in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
     \frac{z}{1+z^2}=\frac{z}{(z-i)(z+i)}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{z-i}+\frac{1}{z+i}\right]
$$
Therefore,
$$
      \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z| > 1}\frac{z}{1+z^2}dz =\frac{1}{2}(1+1)=1.
$$
So it is not possible for $z/(1+z^2)$ to have an anti-derivative in the stated region because if it did have such an anti-derivative $F$, the integral would evaluate to $0$. However, $1/(1+z^2)$ does have an anti-derivative in the stated region.